# How do i make different images move in a circular path

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gsap

i am trying to make different images , move in a circular path . I want it to be responsive at all screen sizes , pleaase how can i do so . You can use a div with a color to show an example of how to make the code work

Comment: Are you wanting several HTML img elements to move in the same circle or in different circles? Please add just enough code to show where you have got to and what your HTML structure is.

Answer (score 0):

im just a noob but with my trash english knowledge i think you need something like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Page title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
    /* Declare canvas screen */
                <canvas style="border: solid 3px" id="the-canvas" width="300" height="400"></canvas>
            </div>
    /* Script*/
            <script>
    /*Declare value to Interactive with canvas*/
                addEventListener('load', function() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
                    var y = x.getContext("2d"); 
        /* x and y is value declare canvas in js*/
                    var imageObject = new Image();
        /*Image object is the thing to Contain image you want draw*/
                    var step = 0, radius = 50, speed = 0.05;
        /* This is r of circle, step for howmany time image go, speed is speed*/
/* Function for spin image around*/
                    function spin() {
    /*Clearrect to clear canvas and print new image in new place*/
                        y.clearRect(0, 0, x.width, x.height);
   /* 0 0 is start of canvas it base on axis and Used for all canvas commands x.width and x.height is canvas width height*/             y.drawImage(imageObject, 100 + radius * Math.cos(speed * step), 200 + radius * Math.sin(speed * step));
                        ++step;
                    }
        /*This function make draw image and change Coordinates every time with cos sin (need math knowledge)*/
     imageObject.onload = function() {
                        y.drawImage(imageObject, 100, 200);
         /* Fps is frame per second*/               setInterval(spin, 50); // 20 fps
                    };
        /*This is path to image in you rom*/
                    imageObject.src = "picturepath";
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This code called Canvas very useful try change heigh and width and picture path

Comment: why not update the `src` attribute of an `img` tag

Comment: This img is in js not in html to use src inside img tag

Comment: then animate with CSS

Comment: I haven't studied there yet :v

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).